# Create Windows Server with Openstack CLI

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, openstack

we´re trying to install Windows Server 2019 with Openstack CLI which generally works fine but after the server has been provisioned, a logon to the server is not possible. How to create the local admin account and automatically add this user to the local administrators group?? We only found instructions for Linux server which works fine with ssh keys but nothing for Windows.

Any help appreciated